# Converting splited string array to a set in Scala

Tags: scala

At the next Scala function:

```
def usersForDepartments(colDeptIds: Option[String]) = Action.async {
    request => {
                 println(colDeptIds)
                 for {
                        users <- Users.getAll(u => u.department in (colDeptIds.getOrElse("").split(";").toSet))
                      }    yield Ok( Json.stringify(convertUsersToJsonOrig(users)))
                }
     }
```

colDeptIds will have values like: "001",  "001;002;003". i.e. it will have a string containing numeric ids like 001, 002, separated by ";".
Each User u has a field called  department. The goal of this function is to get all the users with a  department  value "contained" in colDeptIds but that is not a proper sub-string of any id in that string. To solve this problem I am trying to convert colDeptIds to a set using:

```
(colDeptIds.getOrElse("").split(";").toSet)
```

but I get the error:

```
  scala:82: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  [error]  found   : [B >: String]scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]
  [error]  required: slick.lifted.Query[slick.lifted.Rep[?], ?, ?]
  [error]                                         users <- Users.getAll(u => u.department in (colDeptIds.getOrElse("").split(";").toSet))
```

Any help please? This Scala stuff can be confusing!

Comment: The error says that you are succeeding in creating a `Set[String]` but that's not the correct type for the `in` method.

Comment: u right. I changed in with inSet and it compiled. Thx